# php вывод содержимого через if else

Tags: php, woocommerce

У меня проблема. Мне нужно, чтобы записи отображались в категориях, кроме тех что я ввел. Но если я вставляю, `woocommerce_content();` в if, то они не выводятся нигде, и если else, выводят во всех рубриках, так же в тех, которые я исключил. Помогите!

```
if( has_term( array('furniture','kitchen','furniture'), 'product_cat' )) {
} else {
    woocommerce_content();
}
```

Comment: В цикле проверку проводите?

Comment: да, в цикле....

Comment: Проверьте термины, может где-то ошиблись в написании. Так-то выглядит норм. Проверьте также на одном термине а не на массиве. Ну и попробуйте добавить the_ID() третьим аргументом. Если не поможет - расширьте пример кода в вопросе.